# Form helper input date separated settings

Tags: cakephp

If i do this:

```
$this->Form->input('birth');
```

Form helper will generate the 3 selects (day, month and year). I wanna just month select have a different width but when I specific the settings they do for all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->month('birthday', array('class'=>'form-control', 'empty'=>'Month', 'style'=>'width:33%'));

echo $this->Form->day('birthday', array('class'=>'form-control', 'empty'=>'Day', 'style'=>'width:25%'));

echo $this->Form->year('User.birthday', 1930, date('Y'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'empty'=>'Year', 'style'=>'width:35%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the books...

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements

Expend the options in your input. You should get something like:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('birth', 
array( 
'label' => 'Date of birth', 
'dateFormat' => 'M',
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your questions is a simple CSS problem

If you are using FireFox , install FireBug as Plugin https://getfirebug.com/downloads

After you installed Firebug , right click and choose Inspect Elemetns with Firebug. See pic belove
[image]

and you will see the id of the Select("month") . My case "MatchPlayDateMonth"

[image]

Just override CSS width in CakeGeneric.css. Located under " webroot/css/ " to something like this

```
#MatchPlayDateMonth
{
   width:400px;
}
```